# Visual Studio download stuck at the end

Tags: visual-studio

I am downloading `visual Studio Community 2015 offline` and it stuck at almost 99% for about 4 hours by now.

[image]

I am downloading offline installer using cmd command `<executable name> /layout`

Status in taskbar looks like it is `stoped/paused`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Just Wait.**

I had this exact problem. While the installer was hanging, I checked in the task manager and saw that the `vs_community.exe` process seemed to be active (Memory and CPU usage were fluctuating). So I left the computer on overnight, and in the morning, it had finished the install.

Comment: How is this not an answer?
As I read it, the answer given is to make sure the process is really still working, and continue waiting (possibly overnight).

Comment: I wanted to comment but got a message that I wasn't allowed to...I stumbled upon this question yesterday as I had the exact same problem (stucked 3 hours on 99%). I answered it as the answer I would have liked to find yesterday. I was almost going to cancel the installation, or kill the process.

Comment: I had to cancel the setup. When i'll download next time i'll keep it mind. Thanx though.